# S3 copyObject sends Access Denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know this question has been asked earlier but it's solution is not working for me.

Amazon S3 copyObject is sending me Access Denied error. Object is an image and it's successfully copying the image in S3.

IAM user has been given all S3 rights.
In copyObject, I'm setting the bucket name as well like this:

```
exports.copyObjS3 = (filename, key) => {
  return s3
    .copyObject({
      Bucket: S3BUCKET,
      CopySource: encodeURI(`${S3BUCKET}/${filename}`),
      Key: key,
    })
    .promise();
};
```

`S3BUCKET` specifies name of the S3 bucket.

Can anybody explain me what can be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I had it done by adding ACL option.

```
exports.copyObjS3 = (filename, key) => {
  return s3
    .copyObject({
      Bucket: S3BUCKET,
      CopySource: encodeURI(`${S3BUCKET}/${filename}`),
      Key: key,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    })
    .promise();
};
```

Comment: There is no reason why this should have been needed.  You need to review the IAM user policy or the bucket policy to find an explanation.  Note also that this change makes the destination object readable by anyone, anywhere, without credentials.